# cannot find symbol method getSupportActionBar()

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, swipeview

I know this question has been posted plenty of times, but I still unable to solve even i have tried many solution from **Stack Overflow**.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import com.example.project.myapplication.API.InfoAPI;
import com.example.project.myapplication.Adapter.TabsFragmentPagerAdapter;


public class Edit extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private TabsFragmentPagerAdapter tabsAdapter;
    private String[] activities = new String[]{"Information","Work Force","Work Details"};
    ListView listViewEdit;
    InfoAPI sqlcon;
    private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabsAdapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        actionBar = (ActionBarActivity)getApplicationContext().getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(activities[i]).setTabListener(this));
        }
```

Error is on this line  `actionBar = (ActionBarActivity)getApplicationContext().getSupportActionBar();`

**Error**

```
Error:(48, 63) error: cannot find symbol method getSupportActionBar()
Error:(48, 21) error: incompatible types: ActionBarActivity cannot be converted to ActionBar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `Edit` extend `AppCompatActivity` instead `FragmentActivity`. `AppCompatActivity`  extends  `FragmentActivity` and adds support for the ActionBar. You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

Answer (score 1):

you need to change `FragmentActivity` to `ActionBarActivity`
because this method is not provide in `FragmentActivity` so change.

`public class mainActivity extends ActionBarActivity`

check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100179/android-cannot-resolve-method-getsupportactionbar)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
public class Edit extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
```

with

```
public class Edit extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
```

and you line

```
actionBar = (ActionBar)getApplicationContext().getSupportActionBar();
```