# Actionbar returning null in android studio

Tags: android

I am switching to Android Studio from Eclipse. My app was working well with Eclipse but now I am getting following crash:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.impact.ribony, PID: 21533
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.impact.ribony/com.impact.ribony.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at com.impact.ribony.LoginActivity.showLoginFragment(LoginActivity.java:225)
                                                                       at com.impact.ribony.LoginActivity.loginStatusTest(LoginActivity.java:70)
                                                                       at com.impact.ribony.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:58)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

My Login activity is extending from `FragmentActivity` and my action bar:

```
 ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
```

**Imported libraries:**

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

**My gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.impact.ribony"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':ion')
    compile project(':lib_PagerSlidingTabStrip')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    compile files('libs/circleimageview-1.2.2-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/circleimageview-1.2.2-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/circularimageview-1.1-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/dnsjava-2.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/engine.io-client-0.4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/Java-WebSocket-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/json-org.jar')
    compile files('libs/socket.io-client-0.4.1.jar')
}
```

**Style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar1</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar1</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar1"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#0C0C18</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->

    </style>
</resources>
```

As I said above it was working well with Eclipse. I didn't change any code. But in eclipse my target api was 19 and now 21. I don't know maybe this is the problem. I think I am doing something wrong with support libraries.

How can I fix this problem? (Without changing code if it is possible)

Comment: post your **styles.xml** file

Comment: Maybe you should try **getSupportActionBar()**.

Comment: It is not working with FragmentActivity. Also same code was working with eclipse. I think I have to run same code because If I change it now then other bugs can appear.

Comment: Hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102696/cannot-find-symbol-method-getsupportactionbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend from ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity. Here is a fragment from FragmentActivity [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html):

> Note: If you want to implement an activity that includes an action bar, you should instead use the ActionBarActivity class, which is a subclass of this one, so allows you to use Fragment APIs on API level 7 and higher.

and also use `getSupportActionBar()`